# Getting Started Using Leaflet Draw to CrowdSource Shapes on a Map

Tags: spatial-database, leaflet-draw, crowdsourcing

I want to crowdsource shapes on a map for an organization I'm working with. It seems like [Leaflet Draw](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) something along the lines of the [Mapping Neighborhoods projects](http://www.graphicarto.com/mapping-twin-cities-neighborhoods/). As someone with some experience both working with spatial databases, and making Leaflet maps, I was wondering if there's a tutorial available to get started combining a Leaflet map writing to a database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basing myself on the resources linked in [Thomas Horner's answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/166384/36886) I wrote a [simple example/tutorial on github](https://github.com/radumas/crowdmap-basic) using leaflet and CartoDB. Some key points below.

### Custom SQL Functions

In order to not publicly expose your API key (and allow anyone to do whatever to your data), you should write a custom SQL function in CartoDB to enable the specific actions you want on your table. For example, to insert geometries plus a username and a description of what was drawn to table `crowdmap-basic`, write the following in the [custom SQL tab](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169181/how-do-i-create-and-manage-custom-sql-functions-in-cartodb/169218#169218)

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS insert_crowd_mapping_data(text,text,text);
--Assumes only one value being inserted

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_crowd_mapping_data (
    _geojson TEXT,
    _description TEXT,
    _name TEXT)
--Has to return something in order to be used in a "SELECT" statement
RETURNS integer
AS $$
DECLARE 
    _the_geom GEOMETRY;
BEGIN
    --Convert the GeoJSON to a geometry type for insertion. 
    _the_geom := ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(_geojson),4326); 

    EXECUTE ' INSERT INTO crowdmap_basic (the_geom, description, name)
            VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
            ' USING _the_geom, _description, _name;

    RETURN 1;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql SECURITY DEFINER ;

--Grant access to the public user
GRANT EXECUTE ON FUNCTION insert_crowd_mapping_data( text, text, text) TO publicuser;
```

### Send Leaflet.draw data using AJAX

Look to the Leaflet.draw [documentation](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) on working with Leaflet, or you can use [Mike Foster's tutorial](http://duspviz.mit.edu/web-map-workshop/cartodb-data-collection/). In my example after every drawing is completed a `setData()` function is called, which first converts the drawn item to a GeoJSON to pass to the SQL query (note `.geometry` after `.toGeoJSON()`, the code on the CartoDB tutorial is [incorrect](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/169219/invalid-geojson-when-inserting-data-to-a-cartodb-postgis-table-from-leaflet) )

```
drawnItems.eachLayer(function (layer) {
//Convert the drawing to a GeoJSON to pass to the CartoDB sql database
  var drawing = "'"+JSON.stringify(layer.toGeoJSON().geometry)+"'";

  //Construct the SQL query to insert data from the three parameters: the drawing
  //, the input username, and the input description of the drawn shape
  var sql = "SELECT "+ cartoDBinsertfunction +"(";
sql += drawing;
  sql += ","+enteredDescription;
  sql += ","+enteredUsername;
  sql += ");";
```

And then add the sql query to an AJAX call in order to pass the data to your CartoDB table

```
//TODO: Change to your username
var cartoDBusername = "raphaeld"  
//Sending the data
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'https://'+cartoDBusername+'.cartodb.com/api/v2/sql',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {"q":sql},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      console.log("Data saved");

    },
    error: function (responseData, textStatus, errorThrown) {

        console.log("Problem saving the data");
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Using CartoDB](http://duspviz.mit.edu/web-map-workshop/cartodb-data-collection/)

[Tutorial from CartoDB Blog](http://blog.cartodb.com/read-and-write-to-cartodb-with-the-leaflet-draw-plugin/)