# How do I create and manage custom SQL functions in CartoDB?

Tags: postgresql, carto

I'm working through a [CartoDB tutorial](http://blog.cartodb.com/read-and-write-to-cartodb-with-the-leaflet-draw-plugin/) at the moment, and got to the point of creating a custom SQL function.

Do I just write this in the "CUSTOM SQL QUERY" Field on the right of my table? 
[image: CUSTOM SQL QUERY]
How do I edit previously created functions?

Comment: Based on your screenshot, it looks like that is where you enter the query. Have you tried it? I imagine most users would want to compose the query in a text editor and then paste it in.

Comment: I should maybe edit the question to be emphasize the second question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Custom SQL query` panel of the CartoDB user interface isn't tied to any particular table, but it commonly is used to select the single table you are currently looking at.

So with that, yep, just drop your custom function in their and run it. After it is loaded into your database, you should be able to go back to selecting from your table just like normal.

Comment: I guess I have to use SQL commands to find previously created functions? There's no viewer?