# Invalid GeoJSON when inserting data to a CartoDB (PostGIS) table from Leaflet

Tags: postgis, leaflet, carto, geojson

I've been following along to [this](http://blog.cartodb.com/read-and-write-to-cartodb-with-the-leaflet-draw-plugin/) tutorial from CartoDB.

I create the GeoJSON using:

```
var drawing = "'"+JSON.stringify(layer.toGeoJSON())+"'";
```

and then inserting using a custom SQL function which includes:

```
_the_geom := ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(_geojson),4326);
```

I get the error: `Invalid GeoJSON representation`. I've tried entering the sql my javascript produces directly into the CartoDB console and get the same error. Example below.

```
SELECT insert_data(
'{"type":"Feature","properties":{},
"geometry":{"type":"Point",
"coordinates":[-71.11295700073242,42.37896312335581]}}')
```

Reading the [documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_GeomFromGeoJSON.html) on the function I read "`ST_GeomFromGeoJSON` works only for JSON Geometry fragments. It throws an error if you try to use it on a whole JSON document." Could the error I get be because of the empty properties object?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON` really only expects to be fed the `geometry` portion of the object, so this works:

```
select st_astext(st_geomfromgeojson(
       '{"type": "Point",
         "coordinates": [-71.11295700073242,42.37896312335581]}'
));
```

So you'd want something more like this in your JS:

```
var drawing = "'"+JSON.stringify(layer.toGeoJSON().geometry)+"'";
```

Comment: can you specify a specific projection used ? (e.g different from EPSG:4326)

Comment: If your coordinates are not lon/lat just wrap ST_SetSRID() around the whole thing.